# Using <defs> and line-markers in an SVG inside of ReactJS

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I'm using an SVG tag in a webapp with a lot of nested `<g>`s inside it, most of which are defined in other react files. The top level SVG code looks like this:

```
    <defs>
        <marker id="circleMark" markerWidth="3" markerHeight="3" refx="0" refy="3" orient="auto">
            <circle fill="red" cx="0" cy="0" r="2"/>
        </marker>
        <marker id="arrowMark" markerWidth="3" markerHeight="3" refx="0" refy="3" orient="auto">
            <path 
                d="M 0 0 L 0 6 L 9 150 L 200 50" 
                stroke="red" 
                strokeWidth="3" 
                fill="none"  
                />
         </marker>
    </defs>

    { childPaths }
</svg>
```

With the children definitions being rendered elsewhere. I want to define some `line-marker`s and use them in the paths in the children, but I'm not sure how to reference a `def` from another file  - should I define these shapes in a JS object instead? If so, how would I reference them in the `marker-end` property of the path?

Comment: something like marker-start: url(thefile.svg#circleMark)

Comment: If I'm defining the SVG inside a JS file, can I assign a url to it, or is there a generated one somewhere?
Thanks for your response!